# Service path cannot be found but file exists

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-service

I have several services that used to run on Windows Server 2003 and are now meant to run on Windows Server 2008 R2. They are all 32 bit.

They install OK in 2008 but when I try to start them I get this error:

```
---------------------------
Services
---------------------------
Windows could not start the Blabla service on Blablabla.

Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The paths definitely exist and the "program files (x86)" issue has been taken care of.

Why would they not start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. The Windows error message is a blatant lie.

The service couldn't connect to a database. Turns out the service did start, read its INI file, then did a few things and finally collapsed because it couldn't connect to its database.

Windows then reported the wrong error.